# How many subgroups of order $3$ does a non-abelian group of order $39$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

How many subgroups of order $3$ does a non-abelian group of order $39$ have ?

My work : let $n_{13}$ and $n_3$ denote the number of sylow subgroups of a non-abelian group $39$ have .

Then $n_{13}$ is not zero by Sylow's theorem and $n_{13}|3 , n_{13}=1(\mod 13) $ . This two equation give solution $n_13= 1 $ . So $G$ has exactly  one subgroup of order $13$ .

Now $n_3|13 , n_3=1(\mod 3) $ . This two equations give solutions $n_3=1 or 13 $.

Assume $n_3=13$ . Then there are $1+(13-1)3=27$ elements  order $3$ . So Now we have $27$ elements of order $3$ and $1$ element of order $13$ . But the group has $38$ non-identity element . Sine the only possible order of the non-identity elements of $G$ are $3$ and $13$ . This shows lack of lack enough group elements . Hence $n_3\neq 13$ . So $n_3$ must be $1$ .

Is my solution correct ?If not you are welcomed to provide a solution . Thank you .

Comment: If you think about it, your solution cannot be correct becuase it would imply that there was no nonabelian group of order $39$, in which case the question would make no sense.

Comment: There are lots of mistake in the proof. First of all $n_{13}=1$ implies there are 12 elements of order 13 and not 1 which you have written. The other thing is that if you look at the proof if $n_{3}=1$ then there are only 2 elements of order 3 and (1 element of order 13 according to what you have written) then what are the order of other elements it has to be 39 whence it is cyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n_3=13$, then there should be $13*(3-1)=26$ elements of order $3$. This is because there are $13$ distinct subgroups of order $3$ while each subgroup has $2$ elements of order $3$. Also, note that each pair of subgroups of order $3$ intersect trivially.

If $n_3=1$, then $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $3$,say $P$.
Note that $G$ has also a normal subgroup of order $13$,say $Q$.
Hence $G=P\times Q$ which is abelian since $P$ and $Q$ are both abelian, a contradiction.

So $n_3$ must be $13$ and the number of elements of order $3$ are $26$.

Answer (score 2):

Alan's proof is perfectly fine. But if you want to go by an order argument. Then as you have shown $n_{13}$=1. So there are 12 element of order 13. If $n_3$ would have been 1 you would get 2 elements of order 3. But then there are more elements remaining, whence there should be an element of order 39 which will make G cyclic and hence commutative. So only choice is $n_{3}=13$ and hence you have 26 elements of order 3.

For a general information,  A group of order 39 is either cyclic or else there is a unique non-abelian subgroup of order 39 upto isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

We know that there is only one subgroup of order $13$(By Sylow's thm) which implies there are exactly $12$ elements of order $13$ (precisely the non-identity elements of the subgroup of order $13$).
Now every element has either order=$3$ or order=$13$ or order=$1$ (by Lagrange's thm).
No of elements of order $1$ is $1$ which is the identity of the group which is unique.

So all the other elements are of order $3$ so the ans is $39-12-1=26$